# Некорректно отображается кнопка JButton в SWING

Tags: java, swing

Приложение - будущий калькулятор. Делается клавиатура для него, вопрос встал с некорректным отображением одной-единственной кнопки из массива, остальные работают.
Логика написания: Есть массив с именами для кнопок. Все кнопки создаются двойным циклом, который проходит по массиву. В его же теле задаются как координаты, так и размеры. Все отображается правильно, КРОМЕ последней кнопки, которая занимает весь экран. Все остальные кнопки работают, и нажимаются под ней (см.изображение).

```
public class JFrameToCalc extends JFrame {
     @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public JFrameToCalc(){
    setTitle("Мой калькулятор");// название окна
    setVisible(true);
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    
    String[][] namesOfButtons ={
        {"1", "2", "3", "+"},// Графическое отображение клавиатуры. Массив будет создавать имена кнопок.
        {"4", "5", "6", "-"}, 
        {"7", "8", "9", "/"}, 
        {"(", "0", ")", "*"}, 
        {"/2", "/8", "/10", "/16"}
    };// Конец Массива. 
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {//цикл создает кнопки, и присваивает им имена в соответствии с именами в массиве
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {//i проходится по массивам, j - по именам
            JButton button = new JButton (namesOfButtons[i][j]);
            button.setBounds(j*(50+10)+10, i*(50+10)+60, 50, 65);
            add(button);    }//конец inner цикла
        }  //конец outer цикла
        } //конец конструктора
    };//конец класса
```

[image: некорректное отображение последней кнопки]

Answer (score 0):

```
public class test1 extends JFrame {
    @SuppressWarnings("empty-statement")
    public test1(){
    setTitle("Мой калькулятор");// название окна
    setSize(1000, 1000);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(false);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    
    // Графическое отображение клавиатуры. Массив будет создавать имена кнопок.
    String[][] namesOfButtons ={
        {"1", "2", "3", "+"},
        {"4", "5", "6", "-"}, 
        {"7", "8", "9", "/"}, 
        {"(", "0", ")", "*"}, 
        {"/2", "/8", "/10", "/16"}
    };// Конец Массива. 
    //цикл создает кнопки, и присваивает им имена в соответствии с именами в массиве 
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {//i проходится по массивам, j - по именам
            JButton button = new JButton (namesOfButtons[i][j]);
            button.setBounds(j*(50+10)+10, i*(50+10)+60, 50, 50);
            getContentPane().add(button);    }//конец inner цикла
        }  //конец outer цикла
    setVisible(true);
    } //конец конструктора
};//конец класса
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).